# Passing a list through a function positional argument issue

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops

So I've used the below code to 1)grab all .docx files 2)convert them to csv files 3)create dataframes for each file. The issue is that once I run the code, I get the following error, "TypeError: Document() takes from 0 to 1 positional argument but 450 were given". I think this issue is coming from passing the list as an argument. Could someone point me out how to fix this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
from docx import Document

files = []       
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r"path"): 
    for name in files:
        # For each file we find, we need to ensure it is a .docx file before adding
        #  it to our list
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, name))[1] == ".docx":
            document_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))

def read_docx_tables(*files, tab_id=None, **kwargs):
    """
    parse table(s) from a Word Document (.docx) into Pandas DataFrame(s)

    Parameters:
        filename:   file name of a Word Document

        tab_id:     parse a single table with the index: [tab_id] (counting from 0).
                    When [None] - return a list of DataFrames (parse all tables)

        kwargs:     arguments to pass to `pd.read_csv()` function

    Return: a single DataFrame if tab_id != None or a list of DataFrames otherwise
    """
    def read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs):
        vf = io.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(vf)
        for row in tab.rows:
            writer.writerow(cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        vf.seek(0)
        return pd.read_csv(vf, **kwargs)

    doc = Document(*files)
    if tab_id is None:
        return [read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs) for tab in doc.tables]
    else:
        try:
            return read_docx_tab(doc.tables[tab_id], **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
            print('Error: specified [tab_id]: {}  does not exist.'.format(tab_id))
            raise
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first and didn't work. That's why I changed the files to *files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help(Document)`:

> Document(docx=None)
>
> ```
> Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
> either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
> *docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
> is loaded.
> ```

So you need to process individual files:

```py
for file in files:
    doc = Document(file)
```

Comment: Still not working. Could you share the code?

Comment: @yeppi what isn't working? Can you share your error details in your question?

Comment: when I execute this, ```dfs = read_docx_tables(files)```, I get ```Package not found at "Filename"```.

Comment: Actually, I found the better way to resolve this!